# Add meta description tag to html head using the controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, meta-tags

How can I add a value to the meta description tag `<meta name="description">` in my html head using a controller action?

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0, string name = "")
    {

        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);

        string seodescription = string.Empty;

        switch (id)
        {
            case 1: { seodescription = "1"; break; }
            case 2: { seodescription = "2"; break; }
            case 3: { seodescription = "3"; break; }
            case 4: { seodescription = "4"; break; }
            case 5: { seodescription = "5"; break; }
            case 8: { seodescription = "6"; break; }
            default: {seodescription = string.Empty; break;}
        }

        if (seodescription != string.Empty)
        {
             // here
        }

   }
```

Comment: You should have been more clear that you were talking about the html head meta description tag. Question edited to include this.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the description in the ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.MetaDescription = "Description to use";
```

And in the view render the <meta> tag.

As probably you are using Layouts and meta tag is in header, you should put the code in the Layout page:

```
@if (ViewBag.MetaDescription != null) {
     <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription">
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way, just for reference:

Put this in your layout file

```
@RenderSection("meta", required: false)
```

And then in your views:

```
@section meta{
   <meta name="description" content="Content from either the view model or just plain text">
}
```

This approach can serve you better in some cases, like if you want a front-end guy to be able to edit the tags.